# Arbitrage, alternative definition, equivalence and limitations (proof)

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, finance

The setting is the one period model of a financial market with $d+1$ assets, where the $0$-th asset is a riskless bond:

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space. Let $\overline\pi \in \mathbb{R}_+^{d+1}$ be an initial price vector with $\pi^0 := 1$. Let $\overline S:=(S^0,S^1,\dots,S^d)$ be the final price vector, where $S^0 \equiv 1+r, r>-1$ and $S^i, i \ge 1$ are non-negative RVs. At inital time, a portfolio $\overline\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ can be chosen. $\overline\pi \cdot \overline\xi$ is the initial price of the porfolio, $\overline\xi \cdot \overline S$ is the final value of the portfolio, where $x \cdot y$ denotes the standard inner product.

**Definition:** $\overline\xi \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ is an *arbitrage opportunity*, if

$\quad$**1.** $\overline\pi \cdot \overline\xi \le 0$,

$\quad$**2.** $\mathbb{P}(\overline\xi \cdot \overline S \ge 0 ) = 1$ and

$\quad$**3.** $\mathbb{P}(\overline\xi \cdot \overline S > 0 ) > 0$.

**(a)**: *There exists an arbitrage opportunity $\overline\xi$ such that $\overline\pi \cdot \overline\xi = 0$.*

**(b)**: *There exists $\overline\eta \in \mathbb{R}^{d+1}$ such that $\overline\pi \cdot \overline\eta <0$ and $\overline\eta \cdot \overline S \ge 0 \  \  [\mathbb{P}]$.*

So far, I was able to show that

**(a)** $\iff$  *Existence of an arbitrage opportunity* $\Leftarrow$ **(b)**.

*Problem.* What can be said about the implication "**(a)** $\implies$ **(b)**"?

Comment: I think your argument shows that it is not the case that (a) $\implies$ (b). Have you had a look at the asset pricing textbook by Duffie? I think this is covered there.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will take a look at it on Monday, when library is open.

Comment: No problem. Sorry I can’t be of more help; it’s been too long since I studied this stuff.

Comment: I appreciate the support regardless. I have deleted my sketch above, however, because I managed to come up with a rigorous proof, which I posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**(a)** $\implies$ **(b)**" is false.

*Proof.* Suppose "**(a)** $\implies$ **(b)**", then "$\neg$**(b)** $\implies$ **$\neg$(a)**".

Suppose $\neg$**(b)**. Then
$$\forall \  \overline \eta\in \mathbb{R}^{d+1} \text{ holds } \quad \textbf{(I) } \overline\pi \cdot \overline\eta \ge 0 \quad \text{ or } \quad  \textbf{(II) } \mathbb{P}(\overline\eta \cdot \overline S < 0)>0.$$

If **(II)** is satisfied for $\overline\eta$, by **2.**, $\overline\eta$ cannot be an arbitrage opportunity. By **(I)** and **1.**, for any arbitrage opportunity $\overline\xi$ must hold $\overline\pi \cdot \overline\xi = 0.$ This already a contradiction to $\neg$**(a)**, which is
$$\forall \text{ arbitrage opportunities } \overline\xi \text{ holds } \overline\pi \cdot \overline\xi <0.$$